# Android Error: type mismatch error: Cannot convert Object to Content

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple application to share images in a grid view in Android. I have created an array but when I tried to create a gridview of those images I got an error with my code that I can't resolve.

This is my code :

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context arg2)
{
  Object localObject;

  this.context = localObject;

    }
    public int getCount()
    {
      return MainActivity.this.mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt)
    {
      return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt)
    {
      return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup)
    {
      if (paramView != null)
      {
        MainActivity.this.imageView = ((ImageView)paramView);
      }
      else
      {
        MainActivity.this.imageView = new ImageView(this.context);
        MainActivity.this.imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(90, 90));
        MainActivity.this.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        MainActivity.this.imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
      }
      MainActivity.this.imageView.setImageResource(MainActivity.this.mThumbIds[paramInt].intValue());
      return MainActivity.this.imageView;
    }
  }
}
```

I got the error here: `Type mismatch error: Cannot convert Object to Content` The error is pointing on localObject

Comment: Is this your code? Or is it decompiled code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Object localObject;</s>

```
Context context;
public ImageAdapter(Context arg2)
{
    this.context = arg2;
}
```

Instead of `MainActivity.this.imageView` use `imageView` (this is not an error)

Also use `@Override` where ever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using arg2?

Anyway, try to actually typecast the variable:
 `this.context = (Context) localObject;`

Answer (score 0):

**You will use your Base Adapter like this and update your Grid-view like below code..**

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private int imageWidth;

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths, int imageWidth) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.filePaths = imagePaths;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.filePaths.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.filePaths.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // get screen dimensions
    Bitmap image = decodeFile(filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
            imageWidth);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    return imageView;
}

public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
    try {

        File f = new File(filePath);

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
        int scale = 1;

        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

set the adapter value to the GridView,Imagepaths i have stored my images in SD-card so only i give the paths to adapter...All the best

```
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    // loading all image paths from SD card
    imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();

    // Gridview adapter
    adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(GridViewActivity.this, imagePaths,columnWidth);

    // setting grid view adapter
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```